# How to handle "OSError: Cannot seek back after getting firstbytes" when trying to extract jpg files into numpy array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zip

I'm trying to collect all images in a zip file into a numpy array.

Always getting an error:
OSError: Cannot seek back after getting firstbytes!

```
import urllib.request
import os
import zipfile
import scipy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import imageio
from os.path import splitext

url = 'https://github.com/yoavram/Sign-Language/raw/master/Dataset.zip'
filename = '../data/sign-lang'
if not os.path.exists('../data'):
    os.mkdir('../data')
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)

for file in zf.namelist():
    basename,extension = splitext(file)
    if extension == '.jpg':
        with zf.open(file) as img_file:
            img = imageio.read(img_file)
```

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem for the longest time.

The problem is that `imageio.read()` expects bytes but is being provided with a file-type object.

To fix this, simply read the bytes from the file.

`img = imageio.read(img_file.read())`

Also, if you want numpy arrays you should use `imageio.imread()`